# How to get the value form the constructer within the same type

Tags: function, types, constructor, julia

I have the following struct:

```
struct Test1
    argument
    argumentField
    function Test1(argument)
       return new(argument, argField(argument,Float64,"this is description",10.5,5.5))
    end
end
```

`argFiedl()` will assign a value to the `argumentField` after it checks `argument`, that's why it is necessary to call it within the constructor.
let's assume:

```
test1=Test1(9.5)
```

Whoever now when I call test1 I get:

```
Test1(9.5, Field{Float64}("this is description", 5.5, 10.5))
```

my Approach is that when I call test1 should I get:

```
Test1(9.5)
```

and when I call `test1.getField()` I should get:

```
Field{Float64}("this is description", 5.5, 10.5)
```

so I need to define another function in the struct, but the problem is how can I access the `argument` in the constructor ?

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand the question, but the `new` statement does not have to be the final line of the inner constructor: you can perform additional operations after the `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Julia does not use the usual object-oriented syntax like `test1.getField()`. Since you want just `Test1(9.5)` when you print the variable `test1`, one way to do what you want is

```
struct Test1
       argument
end

function getargfield(t::Test1)
       return argfield(argument, Float64, "this is description", 10.5, 5.5)
end
```

Then when you do `test1=Test1(9.5)` and print `test1`, you get just `Test1(9.5)` as you expect. And when you want the `argumentfield`, you call `getargfield(test1)` you'll get `Field{Float64}("this is description", 5.5, 10.5)`.

Here, only the argument variable is part of the `Test1` type, and the argumentfield is contructed whenever you call the `getargfield` function.

(If you do want the argumentfield to be part of the type but just not printed when you output `test1`, we should likely first clarify why that is and what your goal here is. Please comment below if this is the case.)

Comment: Thank you, but I do need argumentfield to be part of the Type because it has to be called in the constructor. For example test1(20.0) should show me an error because of argumentfield() and I should not define the argumentfield() twice, because the idea is I have to keep the code small, but I did not matter if it gets too complex. :)

Comment: `test1(20.0)` is not a valid call here; if you mean `Test1(20.0)`, then your question says you want that call to work i.e. you have the line of code `test1=Test1(9.5)` in the question. So it's not clear what you mean by saying it should show you an error. This question could do with a lot more clarity in general (argumentfield seems to be a variable in the code in the question, but in the comment you're calling it like a function; it's unclear what you mean by "define the argumentfield() twice"; etc.) I suggest updating the question wtih more description of what you're trying to accomplish and

Comment: ...what you expect to work and not work (give errors).

Comment: A method doesn't have to be part of a type to be called in the type's constructor, that's not even typical for other languages, OOP or otherwise. It's also not typical to want a type to have a field sometimes and not other times, you either have the type to hold that field every time or you put that field in another type. You might customize `Base.show` for a type to omit printing some fields, but those fields are still going to be part of it.